# How to rewrite my regex for match correct user nicknames?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have sample regex for check user nickname:

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9_](?:[a-z0-9]+)*$
```

This regex match correct nicknames:

1. username
2. username16

But can't match like this correct nicknames:

1. username_16

In generaly how rewrite my regex for regx which can ignore sample wrong user names:

1. 16username
2. _username
3. username_

User nickname string on start can contain only `a-z` letters and in the middle (center) of string can contain `a-z0-9_` and on the end can contain only `a-z0-9`

Comment: Add plus to the second square braces `[a-z0-9_]+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffQpyZ/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]` - a lowercase ASCII letter
- `(?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?` - an optional sequence (it will make possible to match 1-char input) of

  - `[a-z0-9_]*` - 0+ lowercase letters, digits or `_`
  - `[a-z0-9]` - a lowercase ASCII letter or digit
- `$` - end of string

If there is a limit to the minimum chars in the input more than 1, you may remove the optional capturing group parentheses/quantifier and use

```
^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9]$
```

And vice versa, to also allow an empty string, wrap with another optional group:

```
^(?:[a-z](?:[a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9])?)?$
 ^^^                            ^^
```

There may be other ways to write the pattern, e.g.

```
^(?=[a-z])[a-z0-9_]*$(?<=[a-z0-9])
```

that will match a string consisting of lowercase letters, digits or `_` where the first char must be a lowercase letter and the last one should be either a letter or a digit.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ffQpyZ/2).

Comment: Why not just `^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9]$`? The difference is: yours accepts `a`, mine no 1-letter usernames. The original poster said usernames need a start and an end, so 1-letter usernames would be invalid.

Comment: @ChristopherK. The answer to your question is already in my answer - *an optional sequence (it will make possible to match 1-char input)*, I just did not re-write the pattern but it is exactly what I meant. If OP does not care and there is a minimum char limit on the input, then `^[a-z][a-z0-9_]*[a-z0-9]$` might also do.